# how to fix /bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected "(" without changing to /bin/bash

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have this makefile:

```sh
SHELL = /bin/sh
INSTALL =/usr/bin/install
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(INSTALL)
INSTALL_DATA = $(INSTALL) -m 644
STRIP=$(TARGET_CROSS)strip
EXEC=monApp
SRC= $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ= $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
CXX=$(TARGET_CROSS)g++
CXXFLAGS = -I./include –I$(STAGING_DIR)/include –I(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include/
LDFLAGS = -g -Wall -L$(STAGING_DIR)/lib –lEGL –lGLESv2 –lIMGegl –L$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib
all: $(EXEC)
$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
%.o: %.cpp
    @$(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf src/*.o
    @rm -rf $(EXEC)
install: $(EXEC)
    mkdir -p ./package.release
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $(EXEC) ./package.release/
    $(STRIP) ./package.release/$(EXEC)
uninstall:
    @rm -rf ./package.release/
```

How do I fix this issue without changing to /bin/bash (i do not have bash so i have to use sh)?

Thank you,

Comment: Which line is the errr on?

Comment: I don't see any parentheses in any of the shell commands. Those are all makefile variables that get substituted before running the shell.

Comment: add missing `$` to `(STAGING_DIR)` in the CXXFLAGS

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, after i googled the error i was sure it was because i was not using bash, can't believe i missed something so obvious... it's embarrassing actually:(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fixing a trivial syntax error that would be best marked as 'unlikely to be of use to future visitors' but that reason was (erroneously, IMNSHO) removed (though it may have been being misused, it was a good and valid reason for closing questions such as this).


Comment: @J.F.Sebastian you saved my life

Answer (score 3):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution from J.F. Sebastian here.*

add missing `$` to `(STAGING_DIR)` in the CXXFLAGS

Answer (score 2):

**I removed parentheses from the project folder's name.**

CMAKE cannot build when the absolute path contains parentheses.

The error occurred when building a C++ project with Qt Creator and CMake:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: So remove the Parentheses/Brackets on your project's folder name or somewhere in your path.

Comment: is there another alternative to removing the brackets? I am trying to compile on Windows which has lot of programs stored in `C:/Program Files (x86)/`, so might be difficult to change that without breaking stuff.